# How I obtain final regression equations of linear, polynomial, SVR, Decision Tree, Random Forest method using Python code

Tags: python, constants, regression, equation, coefficients

I'm predicting using the regression methods in the title. I can obtain the constants and coefficients of these methods. How can I get the general regression equation by writing Python code from these variables?

My example polynomial code is as follows,

```
#Polynomial Regression

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 3)
Ex_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(EX)
lin_reg2 = LinearRegression()
b = lin_reg2.fit(Ex_poly,EY)

model2 = sm.OLS(EY,Ex_poly)
print ("Polynomial Regression")
print(model2.fit().summary())

print (b.intercept_) #sabit katsayı
print (b.coef_)      #değişken katsayıları
```

I hope to get Python code to obtain general equations from equation components.

[OLM results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJAml.jpg)